# Is there a graph-drawing tool that will allow me to constrain x, and automatically lay out y?

Tags: graphics, graph, graphviz

I am looking for a tool similar to graphviz that can render graphs, but that will allow me to constrain just the x coordinate of each node. Then, the tool will automatically choose y coordinates to make the graph look neat.

Basically, I want to make a timeline.

Language / platform / rendering medium are not very important.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a neat-looking graph a force-directed algorithm is going to be your best bet. One of the best ones is SFDP (developed by AT&T, included in graphviz) though I can't seem to find pseudocode or an easy implementation. I don't think there are any algorithms this specialized. Thankfully, it's easy to code your own. I'll present some pseudocode mostly lifted form Wikipedia, but with suitably one-dimensional modifications. I'll assume you have `n` vertices and the vector of x-positions is `x`, subscripted by `x.i`.

```
set all vertex velocities to (0,0)
set all vertex positions to (x.i, random)
while (KE > epsilon)
    KE = 0
    for each vertex v
        force = (0,0)
        for each vertex u != v
            force = force + (0, coulomb(u, v).y)
            if u is incident to v
                force = force + (0, hooke(u, v).y)
        v.velocity = (v.velocity + timestep * force) * damping
        v.position = v.position + timestep * v.velocity
        KE = KE + |v.velocity| ^ 2
```

here the `.y` denotes getting the y-component of the force. This ensures that the x-components of the positions of the vertices never change from what you set them to be. The `epsilon` parameter is to be set by you, and should be something small compared to what you expect  `KE` (the kinetic energy) to be. Also, `|v|` denotes the magnitude of the vector `v` (all computations are of 2-vectors in the above, except the KE). Note I set the mass of all the nodes to be 1, but you can change that if you want.

The `Hooke` and `Coulomb` functions calculate the respective forces between nodes; the first is linear in distance between vertices, the second is quadratic, so there is a guaranteed equilibrium. These functions look something like

```
def hooke(u, v)
    return -k * |u.position - v.position|

def coulomb(u, v)
    return C * |u.position - v.position|
```

where again most computations are in vector form. C and k have real values but experiment to get the graph you want. This isn't usually necessary because the scaling factors will, in two dimensions, pretty much expand or contract the whole graph, but here the x-distances are set so to get a good-looking graph you will have to change the values a bit.